# I need mysql resultset having only index based

Tags: php, mysql

Now we can access the values from mysql result set based on the index and/or with the name.

For eg: SELECT name,id FROM tbl_user

name = resultset[0] OR name = resultset['name']

I need to retrieve the values from mysql result set with only index or with name.

i am using PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.
[mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)  can be used. Use make of the second optional parameter to get the result in desired array type.

```
array mysql_fetch_array ( resource $result [, int $result_type = MYSQL_BOTH ] )
```

result type can be `MYSQL_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_NUM` or `MYSQL_BOTH` (default)
you can also use the [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php), if you need result only an associative array.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
mysql_fetch_array($resultset);
```

or to get associative array use

```
mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset);
```

Check this link for details [mysql fetch array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)